# `display:none` is still leaving border which breaks layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a dynamic menu.  I add and remove elements using `display:none`.

I notice this removes the element but not the elements border.  As usual in CSS I find this odd and don't know if it is a bug or expected behavior and what the work around is.

Here is the menu:

**HTML**

```
<nav id="top_menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="main_nav" href="javascript:;">Favs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="feed_nav" href="javascript:;">Feed</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="set_nav" href="javascript:;">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="fav_nav" href="javascript:;">MyFavs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="so_nav" href="javascript:;">SignOn</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav { 
  display: none; 
  width: 100%; 
  top: 40px; 
  z-index: 999;
}
nav ul li { 
  display: block;
  float: none; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 
  border-left: none; 
}
nav ul li a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 0 15px; 
  line-height: 40px; 
  color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

Here is where I turn the 2 buttons off

```
Backbone.on('user_sign_out', function() {
  self.E.so_nav.innerHTML = 'SignOn';      
  self.E.fav_nav.style.display = "none";
  self.E.set_nav.style.display = "none";
});
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image]

I verified that this is in fact the 2 elements by going into the Chrome debugger and deleting the elements.  This solved the problem in the debugger.

Here is what it looked like before I set `display:none`

[image]

Comment: Could you create a class 'hidden' that you toggled on and off which did `display: none, border: 0`?

Comment: It appears to me that you "turn off" the "<a>", but not the "<li>".

Comment: I saw a site that did that for mobile only, I can do it just as easily for "logged in only"

Comment: An element with `display: none` will definitely **not** show its border. There's something else going on.

Comment: as some have suggested, it's not clear if you're hiding the <a> or <li> and it looks like you're hiding the <a> when you should be hiding the <li>

Answer (score 4):

`display:none` makes things completely not a part of rendering at all.

Your problem is that you have the border on the `<li>` element containing the `<a>` element, and it's only the `<a>` element you're turning to `display:none`. So of course the border would still show...the element with the border isn't the one you turned to `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:none;` for parent, because you set this for `<a>` node, but `<li>` which is `<a>` parent has got border. That's why it doesn't disappear.